# ndk assertion failure Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk, makefile, java-native-interface

When I try to run ndk-build i get this error:

/home/adam/programs/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/setup-toolchain.mk:20: *** Android NDK:  Assertion failure: TARGET_PLATFORM is not defined    .  Stop.

1. I am in the root project directory (I have also tried the jni folder but same thing)
2. I am giving the fully qualified path of the ndk-build
3. Not only is this happening with my new project, but this error also occurs with the sample app that comes with the ndk (hello-jni).
4. I had no problems using ndk with Windows CMD Prompt and Cygwin.  Ubuntu 13.04 is the only Linux environment i have tried.
5. I am using ndk-r8e linuxx86_64 (as you can already tell by the error message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for one reason or another deleting the old NDK and unpacking a new one solved the problem. Same version and everything.  Some files must have been corrupt.